# I am trying to convert numbers to currency and add numbers with 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a simple form that users input number values into (though the fields are text fields).  I am trying to do 2 things:

The first is convert a number string (123456 or 123456.75) into a dollar value with 2 decimal places ($123,456.75) after the user leaves the field.

So user enters 123456.75 and on leaving the field it is converted to $123,456.75

The second related problem is to calculate 2 numbers and format the answer into a dollar value:

```
field1 = 24.75
field2 - 24.24
```

I need field3 to be $48.99

Here is what I have so far on the second problem (this script is tied to a button):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field3').value = 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('field1').value) +  
    parseInt(document.getElementById('field2').value);"
```

This gives me an answer but to 0 decimal places. (24.75 + 24.05 = 48)

Thanks in advance if you can help

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` will remove all decimal places. Try using `parseFloat` instead along with `Math.round`.

ex. (for 2 decimal places)

```
Math.round((parseFloat("24.75") * 100))/100
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruXee/3/)**

Comment: what if you always want the two decimals after the dot like 24.00 or 24.80 ?

Comment: I am still doing something wrong.  I now have       onclick="document.getElementById('field3').value = 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field1').value))) + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field2').value)));"  but field3 is still returning 0 decimal points (12.12 + 12.12 = 24)

Comment: sorry...I clearly didnt follow instructions.  Thanks all set.

Comment: I guess my question wasnt complete (or I'm just pushing my luck)...either way.  Can I then format the answer number into $2,434.24 (keeping the commas and dollar sign?  And the previous solution worked in one regard but is causing issues in another.  The decimal points are carrying out at least 16 digits...thoughts?

Comment: @G use toFixed(2) to make it just go out 2 decimal places... for the commas that would be a bit different. Ill try and whip something up real quick when I have a minute.